# How to convert a MySQL 5.7 JSON NULL to native MySQL NULL?

Tags: mysql, json, casting, null

This code:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"hello": null}', '$.hello')
```

Returns `null`.

However, this is not the MySQL native `NULL`. For example, this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT('{"hello": null}', '$.hello'), 'world')
```

also yields `null`.

How do I convert this JSON `null` to MySQL native `NULL`?

I suppose that I could use `IF` with some comparisons but it doesn't seem like the proper way to do it...

Comment: what is generating the JSON you are parsing with this?  Is it possible for it to send a NULL value instead of null?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus I don't think MySQL allows that. AFAIK only JSON values are allowed. Consider that this issue also manifests in this snippet: `SELECT COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_OBJECT("hello", NULL), '$.hello'), 'world')`

Comment: and why the down vote..?

Comment: Are you trying to filter on JSON null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is about MySQL 5.7, but I would like to add the solution for MySQL 8.0.

With MySQL 8.0.21 we have now the possibility to use the [`JSON_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-value) function (part of SQL Standard) to extract and optionally convert the value to a (MySQL) type.

```
mysql> SET @doc = '{"a": null}';

mysql> SELECT JSON_VALUE(@doc, '$.a' RETURNING SIGNED);
+------------------------------------------+
| JSON_VALUE(@doc, '$.a' RETURNING SIGNED) |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                     NULL |
+------------------------------------------+

mysql> SET @doc = '{"a": 2}';

mysql> SELECT JSON_VALUE(@doc, '$.a' RETURNING SIGNED);
+------------------------------------------+
| JSON_VALUE(@doc, '$.a' RETURNING SIGNED) |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                        2 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately `CAST('{}' AS JSON)` will not work is this case,
but `NULLIF` works:

1. Full methods:

   `SELECT NULLIF(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT('{"hello": null}', '$.hello')), 'null') IS NULL;`
2. Shorted:

   `SELECT NULLIF(helloColumn ->> '$.hello', 'null') IS NULL IS NULL;`

Comment: This should be marked the best answer (not all of us can get all the way to version 8.0.21).

Comment: This has a potential flaw, as I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75683755/15602349).

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have a table called 'mytable' that contains a json column called 'data'. I usually have to use a construct like this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN data->>'$.myfield' = 'null' THEN NULL ELSE data->>'$.myfield' END myfield
FROM mytable
```

Or create a virtual field as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD myfield VARCHAR(200) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
  CASE WHEN data->>'$.myfield' = 'null' THEN NULL ELSE data->>'$.myfield' END
) VIRTUAL;
```

Comment: The `null` in JSON doesn't equal `null` string in MySQL, at least for my 5.7.22

Answer (score 2):

## Intro

Let's assume you have a table with a column `j` of type `JSON` and for that column you have a nested property that is nullable. Example:

```
{"hello": "world"}
{"hello": null}
...
```

In MySQL 5.7.13+, the easiest way to select the `hello` values would be with something like this:

```
SELECT j->>'$.hello' FROM ...
```

However, the result of that query would have `null` *string* ([`LONGTEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)) values instead of the special SQL [`NULL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) values:

```
world   -- that's a string
null    -- that's also a string
...
```

One way to verify that would be to run something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(j->>'$.hello', 'YouWillNeverSeeMe:(((')
```

What might look even stranger is that if we used [`->`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path) instead of [`->>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path), we'd get:

```
"world"   -- that's a string (note the quotation marks)
null      -- that's also a string (with no quotation marks)
...
```

## Solution

So how do we get the JSON `null` values as SQL `NULL` values?

##### MySQL 8.0.21+

In MySQL 8.0.21+ we can use the [JSON_VALUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-value) function and do something like this:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(j->'$.hello', '$') FROM ...
```

The result would be:

```
world   -- that's a string
[NULL]  -- that's NOT a string but the special SQL NULL value
...
```

Note that if we used `->>` instead of `->` here, we would fetch:

```
[NULL]  -- that's NOT a string but the special SQL NULL value
[NULL]  -- that's NOT a string but the special SQL NULL value
...
```

##### Older MySQL (incl. 5.7)

I am not aware of an ideal solution. The [answer provided by sergolius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53498616/15602349) looks simple and nice, but it has a potential flaw one should consider. Let's say Alice and Bob were blessed with a kid and they decided to name it Null (hey, I'm not here to judge!). And let's say Null ended up in our DB's JSON column. So instead of fetching:

```
Alice
[NULL]
Bob
Null
John
...
```

, we might end up with:

```
Alice
[NULL]
Bob
[NULL]   -- Oops! Where did Null go?
John
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks [official discussion](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85755) is under progress but not much active.

Here is one more jury rigging:

```sql
mysql> SELECT CAST('null' AS JSON), JSON_TYPE(CAST('null' AS JSON)) = 'NULL';
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| CAST('null' AS JSON) | JSON_TYPE(CAST('null' AS JSON)) = 'NULL' |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| null                 |                                        1 |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@version;
+---------------+
| @@version     |
+---------------+
| 5.7.21-20-log |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(IF(JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT('{"hello":null}', '$.hello')) = 'NULL', NULL, JSON_EXTRACT('{"hello":null}', '$.hello')), 'world');
```

Comment: Some words of explanation usually are appreciated on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom defined function `TO_NULL` by running:

```sql
-- To check if JSON value is null, if so return SQL null, and if not return original JSON value.
-- There are two nulls, SQL null and JSON null, they are not equal.
-- More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795654
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TO_NULL;
CREATE FUNCTION TO_NULL(a JSON) RETURNS JSON
BEGIN
    RETURN IF(JSON_TYPE(a) = 'NULL', NULL, a);
END;
```

And than use it like so:

```
SELECT TO_NULL(JSON_EXTRACT('null', '$')) IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following approach works for both `undefined` and `null` values in mysql 8

```sql
SELECT data,
       CAST(data->>'$.a' AS JSON) <=> CAST('null' AS JSON) 'null',
       data->>'$.b' IS NULL 'NULL' FROM t;
```

| data | null | NULL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {"a": null} | 1 | 1 |

So to check if field has no value you can use in your query something like this

```sql
SELECT CAST(data->>'$.a' AS JSON) <=> CAST('null' AS JSON) OR data->>'$.a' IS NULL FROM t;
```